# Can't Figure out why a row isn't being selected in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So in my activity table there is a activity called Telephone Skills

in column activity.act_id '174'

in column activity.des 'Telephone Skills

it doesn't have any supervisors in this activity, so when i out put the data using the query below, I thought it would just have the activity name then a blank column to the right.

unfortunately i just get the 5 other activities and their supervisors skills.

this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    a.des 'Activity Name', 
    group_concat(DISTINCT e.exp_name separator ', ') 'Supervisors Skills'
FROM activity a
JOIN department d
on a.act_id = d.act_id
JOIN supervisor s
on d.sup_id = s.sup_id
JOIN skills sk
on s.sup_id = sk.sup_id
JOIN expertise e
on sk.exp_id = e.exp_id
GROUP BY a.act_id
ORDER BY a.des, e.exp_name ASC;
```

what am i missing to make it out put that last activity name with a blank column to the right?

Comment: You're doing  **INNER** JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't have any supervisors in this activity, so when i out put
>   the data using the query below, I thought it would just have the
>   activity name then a blank column to the right.

So you need `left joins` here:

```
SELECT 
    a.des 'Activity Name', 
    group_concat(DISTINCT e.exp_name separator ', ') 'Supervisors Skills'
FROM activity a
LEFT JOIN department d on a.act_id = d.act_id
LEFT JOIN supervisor s on d.sup_id = s.sup_id
LEFT JOIN skills sk on s.sup_id = sk.sup_id
LEFT JOIN expertise e on sk.exp_id = e.exp_id
GROUP BY a.act_id
ORDER BY a.des, e.exp_name ASC;
```

Comment: what does a left join mean ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN will include all rows from table to the left side of join. In you case activity. And will pick all matching row from table to the right. If no match is found rows from left are not excluded, they are present but have nulls in columns from tables to the right of join. Exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks mate that makes perfect sense.
was reading examples but with ur explanation on my  table it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

This portion of the SELECT clause is giving you the five other activities:

```
DISTINCT e.exp_name separator ', ')
```

Someone else will have to explain what needs to be done to display the "last activity name."  That isn't clear to me based on the information in the question.